# jQuery animate colors plugin only works when clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color

Trying to animate background color on page load but it only works when I actually click the element.  I am using the colors plugin.

```
$(window).load(function ()  {  
$(".hilite").toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "yellow" }, 1000);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFF2A8" }, 500);
});
})

<span class="hilite">THIS should change background COLOR</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.hilite').css({'background-color', 'yellow'});
    $('.hilite').animate({ 'background-color' : "#FFF2A8" }, 1000);
});
```

or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('body').animate({ 'background-color': "#FFF2A8" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You must edit your post to include periods in front of `hilite` because it is a `class`

Answer (score 1):

You are using **no** plugin that I can see.

`toggle()` works on click.

Comment: well that would explain why it does only when clicked.